# Making text start two spaces (or 5 pixels) after the end of a variable

Tags: css

For the echoed text below, the "DURING" covers / overlaps the variable `$submittor` if I don't have all of the `&nbsp;`s.  With the `&nbsp;`s, there is too much space between `$submittor` and "DURING" if the length of `$submittor` happens to be a short value.

Is there a way to make "DURING" start two spaces (or 5 pixels) after the end of `$submittor` regardless of the length of `$submittor`?

Thanks in advance,

John

The code:

```
echo '<div class="sitename3name">SUBMITTED BY <a href="http://www...com/.../members/index.php?profile='.$submittor.'" >'.$submittor.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; DURING '.$dt->format('F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a').'</div>';
```

The CSS:

```
.sitename3name { 
   position:absolute;
         width:800px;
         left:31px;
            top:189px;
   color: #999999;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: normal;
   height: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;

}

.sitename3name a{ 
   position:absolute;
   color: #004284;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
   height: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;

}

.sitename3name a:hover{ 
            position:absolute;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color:#FF0000;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
   height: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap "DURING" in a span, float it left and add a 5px left margin:

```
<span class="during">DURING</span>

.during
{
   float: left;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Might work..